# What is the most performant and lighter transport for OpenEJB?

Tags: performance, jakarta-ee, openejb, transport

There are a few transports available for OpenEJB 4.0.0:

1. ejbd
2. ejbds
3. httpejbd

Which one is lighter on the network?

Which one is faster?

Are there any pros and cons of choosing any one of then?

Our application as around 450 clients talking to remote EJBs on a OpenEJB 4.0.0 container. All in a local LAN (but using cascading switches with some redundancy).

Update:

This question is not related to another one on timeouts. We don't have any timeouts or application problems that we could identify. The application works very well when we have a limited number of clients, but when we try it with hundreds we are facing what seems to be network errors: the server logs show recurring "IoExpcetion unkown byte received". Since CORBA ORBs has been reported to have broadcast problems, we were suspecting it might be a RMI over IIOP kind of problem. We are going to try other protocol options to compare against our current set up.

Update (2012-oct-08):

we have run hundreds of tests now, with 450+ clients in a LAN. There is no one size fits all answer. If we have very few clients, EJBD is faster. If we have hundreds of clients, EJBD stops working (it seems to cause switch saturation). With hundreds of clients, httpejbd still works (it seems related to the fact that each remote call creates a short duration http request).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

httpejbd with Jetty can serve many more clients (thousands) but ejbd is significantly faster in the 10s to low hundreds range.

This email has some good info on both from a purely performance perspective:

- http://openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/Remote-client-performance-td987613.html

I'll state once again that the timeouts you're seeing are not related to the client/server performance.  A faster client/server layer will actually **increase** the contingency in the server and make server-side locking issues more apparent.

What I'd recommend is dispelling the idea that it is the protocol layer causing your timeout issues.  It is more likely the number of clients, not the fact that they are remote.  It is possible to execute `@Remote` beans in the same VM as the server via looking them up from the `LocalInitialContextFactory`.  When this is done you get a client reference that adheres to the remote EJB semantics but does not involve any network plumbing.

Have this client spawn off 450 threads, each thread and hit the server with continuous requests in a loop and doing the kind of work regular clients do.  What you'll find is you can reach the timeouts with likely far less than 450 threads (i.e. 450 clients).

Here's a performance analysis of all the ways you can invoke.  This is the same object on the same machine:

POJO

- *245,000 TPS* -- shown for baseline (doesn't get faster than a pojo invocation)
- http://people.apache.org/~dblevins/pojo-performance.png

`@Local`

- *212,000 TPS* -- shows the above, plus the additional cost of basic "EJB" support (interceptors, security, transactions, etc)
- http://people.apache.org/~dblevins/openejb-3.1.4-local-performance.png

`@Remote` via `LocalInitialContextFactory`, server-side

- *112,000 TPS* -- shows the above, plus the additional cost of serialization and pass-by-value remote semantics
- http://people.apache.org/~dblevins/openejb-3.1.4-remote-serverside-performance.png

`@Remote` via `RemoteInitialContextFactory`, client-side (ejbd)

- *31,600 TPS* -- shows the above, plus the additional cost of the network layer
- http://people.apache.org/~dblevins/openejb-3.1.4-remote-clientside-performance.png

So if your gut is telling you that it is the network layer slowing things down and result in access timeouts, validate that assumption by creating a small performance test and run it both with the `LocalInitialContextFactory` and the `RemoteInitialContextFactory`.  The `LocalInitialContextFactory` will show you the theoretical maximum performance you could expect from any remoting layer.

If the problem goes away, you were right and you can proceed with efforts to tune the network layer.  If the problem persists or becomes worse, then you know the issue is not the network layer and you'll need to change focus to make progress.

Comment: This is another problem we are facing, not (at least directly) related to the timeouts (now solved, we don't have any timeout now). The Server logs shows a lot of I/O Exceptions such as "unexpected byte received". Also, some clients get stuck without server responses and some clients constantly repeat an error saying they were not authenticated. We know that most if not all those errors are kind of bogus (we speculate that they are network related), since the same arquitecture works perfectly with a small group of clients. Since we've heard of CORBA broadcast problems we wonder about RMI-IIOP.

Comment: After all adjustments our experiments confirmed this answer (we can handle more clients with httpejbd than with plain ejbd) in our network.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used either of these protocols but I believe a generic view can get you started as I doesn't see a performance comparison of these 3 on internet. I believe the basic native and low level implementation is most of the time faster than higher level protocols. In this scenario ejbds is less performant than ejbd as there is a SSL handshake overhead. I also believe the ejbds is less performant than httpejbd.